# Apply CSS style to specific tick in flot

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I am wondering how we can apply a tick with CSS. let's say, I have a ticks as [10, 100, 200, 500, 1000] and I want 200 to be bigger font and in red color. What I am trying to achieve is mark that tick as threshold value in the graph

```
markings: [ {color: 'red', lineWidth: 3, yaxis: {from:200, to:200}}]
```

This will draw a line but I want to show the tick value to be let me know that this is different than other ticks.

I was trying to do something like this, but apparently this doesn't work, because it's a string. Any ideas or suggestions ?

```
tickFormatter: function(val, axis) {
    if(val == 200) {
        return ("<div style=\"color: 'red'\">200</div>");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1.) Your CSS is invalid:

```
style="color: red" // no quotes around 'red'
```

2.) You also have to return a value when `val != 200`

3.) I'd recommend using a `<span>` tag instead of a `<div>`.

Putting this together:

```
tickFormatter: function(val, axis) {
    if(val == 200) {
        return "<span style=\"color: red\">200</span>";
    } else {
        return val + '';   
    }
}
```

Here's a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CYFV5/).

Comment: for some reason it doesn't work for me in my code, I see the tick as `<span style=\"color: red\">200</span>`

Comment: I am assuming its something to do with timing when the ticks are loaded and the graph is rendered on the canvas, I am not sure how it is supposed to load

Comment: Do you actually see `style=\"` with the escaped quote in the outputted HTML?

Comment: sorry, my bad, i see `<span style="color: red">200</span>`

Comment: Is your site public?  Can you post a link?

Comment: @user525146 Do you see the `<span>...` in the fiddle or only in your own page? If only in your page, try looking at the source code for the x-axis labels and compare it between the fiddle and your own page.